# Kanvas SDK gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash after luanching camera

Tags: ios

I have downloaded Kanvas SDK for photo editing. Followed following steps to integrate into project.

1. Added KanvasCameraSDK framework and KanvasCameraSDKResources bundle into project.
2. Added AVFoundation framework.
3. Added KanvasCameraSDK into embed frameworks into project settings.

Initialized SDK with id and key as follows.

```
 //initialise Kanvas SDK.
NSString* clientID = @"58d23f74014fdd4358d07264";
NSString* SDKKey   = @"MEUCIA7qGn5XEMo1XGaIdyit821qPTGCaPtkpMA5KVdRQxCjAiEA6m2HpXKLyj+XkF/LqHAh2hTz4WghrS7vxApe+sjSiQ0=";

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
BOOL verified = [KanvasSDK initializeWithClientID:clientID signature:SDKKey];
NSLog(@"SDK initialised = %d",verified);
```

After Initializing tried to launch camera which gave crash.

```
KVNCameraViewController *cameraController = [KVNCameraViewController verifiedViewController];
cameraController.delegate = self;
cameraController.gifQuality = kKVNGifQualityMedium;
[self presentViewController:cameraController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Same code works well in sample project, However gives crash when integrated with Application.

https://github.com/tracks/Kanvas-SDK

Comment: did you add key for camera permission in plist ?

Comment: Did you ask permission for camera access? You have to add this in plist NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription
NSCameraUsageDescription

Comment: Yes I have added key. Code works with sample POC but gives crash after integrating with main project. Is there any settings that need to be done?

Comment: If it crashes, do you have a crash log?

Comment: Seems that you are missing AFNetworking. Do you have the documentation to install it? Because the GitHub Link doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for giving time. Please find crash log file link here. https://www.dropbox.com/s/en4v78gwcpusrcb/PurpleTrail%20%2014-04-17%2C%2011-56%20AM.crash?dl=0

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 We have to sign up for kanvas SDK then gets Git hub link for SDK which has documentation. After following these steps I could use it in sample POC

Comment: @GaneshAmrule I dont know why this crash occurs but its work great for me now

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 I suspect that something might be wrong with my project build setting but not able to find it out

Comment: @GaneshAmrule yes may be ...  check that framework path and header path is right or not

Answer (score 1):

Kanvas SDK uses Google analytics Myapp was also using google analytics so static library was included twice in project which was causing crash due to Notifications clean ups. Removing Google Analytics library from my project solved problem.